# Involuntary duplicating node windows

Tags: node-editor

This is Blender 2.9, inside the Shading tab.

I am trying to move the (yellow) Noise Texture but whenever I try to it creates a duplicate (green).
Ive tried to move (yellow) by pressing G as well but same thing happens.
If I select multiple nodes including (yellow) and move those, (yellow) still gets duplicated.

The duplicate only happens the first movement, after it gets duplicated once I can move around both without any further duplicates being made.

Yellow is a shift-D copy from (blue), it would be odd if it has something to do with it but I mention it anyway.

I can easily just delete and re-add (yellow) but this bugs very a lot and I take its valuable to learn now before I get complicated with nodes.

[image: Picture]

Comment: Do you box select or just click on the nodes before duplicating them ? There may be a stacked copy of the blue noise node under it that you accidentally copied too. Otherwise it may be a keymap problem. you can look in the preferences and reset the node interface keymaps if they have been modified

Comment: I was just suggested by another person that it might be a copy as you say. How can I for sure verify this before moving?
If I click select I duplicate, if I box select I move.

Comment: It should only select one node if you click select (unless you somehow activated the circle select with a very low radius but there should be an indication on screen that it is active). Be aware also that if you use SHIFT D but cancel the operation (with right click or escape), the node still gets duplicated but stays at the same place.

Comment: I cant tell if I select 1 or 2 since supposedly they are on top of each other, but I take this is the answer that they are stacked. So Ill just move the top one out and delete it then re-wire.
Ill remember to be wary of how I use shift D next time. thank you bro